# Org-mode properties to list or structured content

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I love the way org-mode allows to input easily resuable data through Properties. Later on you can export it to **CSV** thanks to column-view, and it is very userful.

But what if I would like to export it to a list (unordered list or list definition) or even to a kind **structured content** (eg: h1|h2... list).

As far as I know the document {OPTIONS} {prop:t} export the properties to {} HTML element

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Can you give a simple org snippet and what you wish it was exported to?

Comment: Thank you @JohnKitchin for your interest and my apologies for the delay. What I would like is to convert a table -no matters if this comes from a CSV or an orgmode table made up by column-view- to a hierarchical structure where the name of the column is the heading 1 or the title of the section  and the name of the row would be the name of the heading 2 and its content the content of that section. Best!